# Xamarin Forms CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived not enter in ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I implemented push notifications in android work will, in ios token return but when try to test notifications not received, no error return to fix and didn't know what the problem please any help

I use this plugin to implement firebase **Plugin.FirebasePushNotification** Version 3.4.35 **Xamarin.Forms** Version 5.0.0.2515

this Code in
Add **GoogleService-Info.plist** file make build action BundleResources

Mark in **Entitlements.plist** push notifications to enable

Mark in **info.plist** Enable BackgroundMode (Remote notification), Add

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>  <false/>
```

in **Shared project** add this

```
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications();

        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN : {p.Token}");

            if (p.Token != null)
            {
                AppData.Token = p.Token;
                Api.CustomerService.UpdateTokenbynumber();
            }

        };
        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received");
            System.Console.WriteLine($"**********Received : ");
           
              
            
        };


        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationOpened += (s, p) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Opened");
            
        };


        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationAction += (s, p) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Action");
        };

        CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationError += (s, p) =>
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Errrrrrrroooooooorrrr");

        };
```

this Code in **AppDelegate**

```
  [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
      
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
          

                Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init("AIzaSyAFh07QpEGWHSecHRTxImrctCZAge0WK5o");
                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("IndicatorView_Experimental");
                Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
                global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
            Plugin.LocalNotification.LocalNotificationCenter.RequestNotificationPermission();
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);
            LoadApplication(new App());
           
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
           
        }

        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
            Console.WriteLine($"Firebase registration token: {AppData.Token}");
        }

     
        public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
        {
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.RemoteNotificationRegistrationFailed(error);

        }
        // To receive notifications in foregroung on iOS 9 and below.
        // To receive notifications in background in any iOS version
        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
            // this callback will not be fired 'till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

            // If you disable method swizzling, you'll need to call this method. 
            // This lets FCM track message delivery and analytics, which is performed
            // automatically with method swizzling enabled.
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
            // Do your magic to handle the notification data
            System.Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
        }


    }
```

this log data

```
    2022-11-21 14:17:32.772818+0200 Najd.iOS[17253:179449] [general] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:] allowed unarchiving safe plist type ''NSNumber' (0x7ff863b6e4d0) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]' for key 'NS.keys', even though it was not explicitly included in the client allowed classes set: '{(
    "'NSMutableSet' (0x7ff863b571d0) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
    "'GDTCOREvent' (0x1019a5168) [/Users/raitotec/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D39EF3A7-186B-4AA8-B1B6-7068F966D261/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6E5BD3FC-B9A7-41F2-95D4-99EE7783B900/Najd.iOS.app/Frameworks/GoogleDataTransport.framework]",
    "'N
SMutableDictionary' (0x7ff863b585f8) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}'. This will be disallowed in the future.
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #2
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Loaded assembly: /Users/raitotec/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D39EF3A7-186B-4AA8-B1B6-7068F966D261/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/6E5BD3FC-B9A7-41F2-95D4-99EE7783B900/Najd.iOS.app/ar/Najd.resources.dll [External]
2022-11-21 14:18:11.996099+0200 Najd.iOS[17253:180223] 6.22.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization.
2022-11-21 14:18:12.071362+0200 Najd.iOS[17253:180223] [general] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:] allowed unarchiving safe plist type ''NSString' (0x7ff863b6d698) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]' for key 'NS.keys', even though it was not explicitly included in the client allowed classes set: '{(
    "'NSDictionary' (0x7ff863b589e0) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
    "'NSDate' (0x7ff863b58878) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}'. This w
ill be disallowed in the future.
Thread started:  #7
2022-11-21 14:18:19.031547+0200 Najd.iOS[17253:179449] **********TOKEN : er8MQGevkkV7rSosJS9_NP:APA91bETxB3GAJQxR728lmHm9rMTaa3jS06nXFDkNcdXJ7pkEi1t3JwxSzqyYk8nH5k90UgZ16WtxDmrzuCA81AzsnTOdh6h_fkVtkmZCgYbaU0cMW1yAJl-K2qSfIlOYbzT0MXBYqU-
2022-11-21 14:18:19.287594+0200 Najd.iOS[17253:180223] [general] *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver validateAllowedClass:forKey:] allowed unarchiving safe plist type ''NSString' (0x7ff863b6d698) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]' for key 'NS.keys', even though it was not explicitly included in the client allowed classes set: '{(
    "'NSDictionary' (0x7ff863b589e0) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
    "'NSDate' (0x7ff863b58878) [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}'. This w
ill be disallowed in the future.
2022-11-21 14:18:19.336678+0200 Najd.iOS[17253:180330] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6000031ee540> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2022-11-21 14:18:19.339800+0200 Najd.iOS[17253:179942] 6.22.0 - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to look out for

1. Make sure your APN's Authentication key is set up on your Firebase console
2. Test on the device. It won't work on the simulator
3. The bundle Action for the GoogleService-info-plist is set to "BundleResource"